# number of visitors gained and lost comparing with previous day - sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE visitors (
Date DATE,
visitor VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO visitors VALUES
("2019-10-01", "v1"),
("2019-10-01", "v2"),
("2019-10-01", "v3"),
("2019-10-02", "v2"),
("2019-10-03", "v2"),
("2019-10-03", "v4"),
("2019-10-03", "v5");
```

please find Find number_of_visitors_per_date, number_of_visitors gained comparing with previous day, and number_of_visitors lost comparing with previous day. The expected results for the above table should be:

```
Date        | number_of_visitors | number_of_visitors_gained | number_of_visitors_lost
2019-10-01  |        3           |             3             |            0
2019-10-02  |        1           |             0             |            2
2019-10-03  |        3           |             2             |            0
```

Obviously, the most challenging part is how to get the last two columns. Note, since there is no previous day for the first day, the `number_of_visitors_gained` is the total number of visitors in the first day, and the `number_of_visitors_lost` is 0.

Comment: please include your attempts as well.

Comment: Is that mysql or mssql?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I can easily get the first column `number_of_visitors`, but no clue for the 2nd and 3rd column

Comment: @Tony Dong: mysql

Comment: @JamesWang: which version of MySQL?

Comment: @GMB I'm using MariaDB actually, v10.3 which support window function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you RDBMS supports window functions, you can aggregate, and then use `lag()`:

```
select 
    date,
    number_of_visitors,
    case 
        when lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by date) is null 
            then number_of_visitors
        when lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by date) < number_of_visitors
            then number_of_visitors - lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by date)
        else 0
    end number_of_visitors_gained,
    case when lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by date) > number_of_visitors
            then lag(number_of_visitors) over(order by date) - number_of_visitors
        else 0
    end number_of_visitors_lost
from (
    select date, count(*) number_of_visitors 
    from visitors 
    group by date
) t
order by date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=55651d5918e83762cec4569461d03695)**:

```
date       | number_of_visitors | number_of_visitors_gained | number_of_visitors_lost
:--------- | -----------------: | ------------------------: | ----------------------:
2019-10-01 |                  3 |                         3 |                       0
2019-10-02 |                  1 |                         0 |                       2
2019-10-03 |                  3 |                         2 |                       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for aggregation using `lead()` and `lag()` window functions:

```
select date, count(*) as visitors_on_day,
       sum(case when prev_vdate is null or prev_vdate <> date - interval 1 day
                then 1 else 0
           end) as gained_visitors,
       sum(case when next_vdate <> date + interval 1 day
                then 1 else 0
           end) as lost_visitors
from (select v.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by visitor) as prev_vdate,
             lead(date) over (partition by visitor) as next_vdate
      from visitors v
) t
group by date
order by date;
```